# iOS development: moving from Objective C to C#

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c

We have an existing iOS app that was built by contractors using completely Objective C.  Our development team would like to begin converting this to C# since that is what we typically use for everything else and we want it to use the same language as the rest of our code.

Is it possible to do this conversion a little bit at a time and have both co-located in the same working app?  Or do we have to a complete conversion?

Comment: How on earth would they talk to each other??? Seems like you are going to have to do a complete conversion.

Comment: Objective-C is the language of choice for native iOS apps. There are wrappers like [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/ios) but they come with severe trade-offs. So far, everyone knowledgeable that I've come across so far  has recommended sticking with Obj-C if you are serious about building a native app with iOS' look & feel and response times

Comment: @LordTakkera: If I knew how they would talk to each other I wouldn't have asked the question. :) As I am not an experienced iOS developer I wasn't sure if there was a means to somehow load modules of differing types and have them communicate to each other.  This sort of thing is very possible in .NET so I thought I'd ask.  Big -1 for everyone who down-voted my question.  SO has sort of become jerk-ville if you ask me.  It was an honest question from someone who doesn't know iOS.  Probably a bunch of stuck-up Apple-ites thinking they're better than everyone else. :) Typical.

Comment: @skb, My apologies for offending you. To my knowledge, C# doesn't talk to anything but CLR assemblies and C++ (hence my comment), I understand why you were asking the question. For the record, I am no fan of Apple products :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix C# and Objective C.

If you really want to use C# you have to do a complete conversion and need a 3rd party tool like xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my personal experience, the bigest effort to be produce by C# expert to be able to develop iOS app is not learning the language (Objective-C) but as alway is on learning the new SDK (cocoa touch...).

It's easy to found on the web, some "conversions" documents from C++/C#/Java to Objective-c.

Really, for me, best practice is to learn objective-c on top of the SDK.

As an exemple, Standford courses CS193P (avail for free on iTune-U), don't spend so much time on objective-c compare to the SDK.

Now, for a company, cost are really important, also let compare both options (base on if you learn objective-c) :
 - will cost approx 2 weeks of non avail of the dev
 - You'll have to buy a mac (not sure with xamarin)
 - all the doc from Apple are in objective-c (some in C or c++), you will win time
 - If you request help for iOS dev based on objective-c, you will have a big community, not sure for xamarin : you will win time
 - you will not have to re-develop your app : you will win time

PS : of course you can dev on c# on your asp.net server to produce web service for your objective-c app

Now, it's up to you...